# Very odd binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

The number of odd binomial coefficients in each row of Pascal's triangle is always a power of two although their sum rarely is.  One of these rare occasions occurs for numbers of the form $\,$$n = 2^m -2$$\,$$\,$when the sum is exactly half of the total row sum.  [One can see this e.g. by writing the binary expansion of$\,$ $n = 111...110$ $\,$and applying Lucas' classical result to conclude that, for numbers of this form, $\,$$ {n \choose k}$$\,$ is odd iff $\,$$k$$\,$ is even.]$\;$So this at least gives an infinite sequence of integers $\,$$2,6,14,30,...$$\;$which exhibit this odd behavior.  Are there any other examples?

Question:$\;$If $\;$$\Sigma$${n\choose k}$ $=$$\,$$2^{n-1}$$\;$, where the sum extends over the odd binomial coefficients only, must $\,$$n$$\,$be of the form $\,$$2^m - 2$$\;$?

Thanks

Comment: https://oeis.org/A088560

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately, the claims made there (although plausible) appear to be unsupported by any references or proofs.